# How can i get accurate resultsof mathematical calculations in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

I have a simple mathematical calculation. I have two floats n1 and n2.When I evaluate a simple division on these floats I cannot get accurate result like in a calculator. Here is the simple code

```
float n1=55;
float n2=23;

float n=n1/n2;

NSLog(@"%.15f",n);
```

I see this on console . I wanted to get a precesion upto 15 digits after the decimal hence .15f

```
2.391304254531860
```

But when I calculate the same division of the two floats  in a scientific calculator the value is as follows. How can I get this same value using code?

```
2.391304347826087
```

Am I missing something very silly and obvious? Any help would be of great use.
    TIA

Comment: "How can i get accurate resultsof mathematical calculations in objective-c?" - don't use floating-point numbers.

Comment: He asked for 15 accurate decimal digits of the quotient 55/23, and `double` is perfectly adequate for that on any platform with IEEE doubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `double` type should be used instead of `float` if you need higher accuracy in calculations. `double` uses more bits to store its values than `float`.

Comment: In particular, an IEEE double can provide more than 15 correct decimal digits for a simple division like 55/23.